# Do Java infinite loops need Increment

Tags: java, loops

Hello World, am kinda new To java and oop and I would like to ask if an infinite loop needs an increment for example

```
     for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
       System.out.print("Hello World");
     }
```

so in this loop, there is an increment, so do all types of loop need increment

Comment: No; the increment and test are both optional. Although the idiomatic way to write an infinite loop is just `while (true)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you want to run an infinite loop you could use `while(true)`

```
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

With your `for` you are just doing an useless thing (increment `i` every time).

If you need to keep a "number of times"

```
int x = 0;
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Hello World");
  ++x;
}
```

Or, a for without condition (`for(;;)` is legal!) with

```
for (int x = 0; ; ++x)
{
  System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: will it crash the program and my pc if the increments is not declared

Comment: Yes, you cannot let run something forever (in this way). You need to stop it or your application will be killed as "Not responsive"

Comment: It won't crash the PC (that's a lot harder these days).

Comment: is there a way I can do that(stop it )

Comment: Yes, when you need it call break; to stop the while. Example if (somethingIsTrue) break; <= will stop the while if somethingIsTrue is true.

Comment: @user3526881: *"is there a way I can do that(stop it )"* The best way is to have a reasonable condition in the `while` (or `for`) in the first place. Writing an "infinite" loop you `break` out of is very much a poor second choice.

Answer (score 6):

This loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
   System.out.print("Hello World");
 }
```

is not infinite. It will iterate 4 times, then end. If you wanted an infinite loop, then you could do this:

```
for(;;) {
   System.out.print("Hello World");
 }
```

or:

```
while(true)
{
   System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

So no, only the separating semi-colons in a `for` loop are required.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite loop with for :

```
for(;;) {
   System.out.print("Hello World");
 }
```

Indeed there are infinite ways to create an infinite loop with either `for` or `while` or `do..while` statements, if only the condition never satisfies.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite loop using for()

```
for(;;) {
    System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```